# Fluent NHibernate Error with embedded statements

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

this is my code;

```
    public ActionResult Login(User user, string returnUrl)
    {
        using (ISession session = FluentNHibernateConnect.OpenSession())

        var users = session.QueryOver<User>()
        .Where(user.Nick == "asd")
        .And(user.Password == "1234")
        .List();

    }
```

what is the problem. var and .where(user.nick == "asd") red line ?

Library;

- MvcBlog.Mapping;
- MvcBlog.Models;
- NHibernate;
- NHibernate.Criterion;
- System.Web.Mvc;
- System.Web;
- System.Web.Security;

Answer (score 1):

Where method takes an expression:

```
var users = session.QueryOver<User>()
    .Where(user => user.Nick == "asd")
    .And(user => user.Password == "1234")
    .List();
```

Comment: thank you. but the problem is still ongoing says problem "Delegate 'System.Func<bool>' does not take 1 arguments" continue research :)